# Problem while debug with x64dbg

Tags: x64dbg, debug

I am debugging with x32dbg a program (x) which at some point opens another program (y). Is it possible to continue debugging also on program (y) when opened by the first one (x)?
Unfortunately, program y must necessarily be opened by x otherwise an error will occur, so it is not possible to debug program y individually.
Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Yes look for an option to debug the child  it should be there in options   menu iirc

Comment: I don't find the option in menu